# Rails 3: named routes with shorthand notation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

Let's say in Routes.rb, you have:

```
resources users
  member do
    post action1  # POST /users/:id/action1
    get action2  #GET  /users/:id/action2
  end
end
```

How can you name the path so that you can all, `user_action1_path(@user)`?

In the regular notation you can do

```
match "users/:id/action1", "users#action1", :as => :user_action1
```

But how do you do it using shorthand notation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need that?

You already have `action1_user_path(user)` available.

Comment: Cool! Didn't know you can do that. Thanks!